# User level based navigation

Tags: php, oop, class, yii

I am following this tutorial:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/191/implementing-a-user-level-access-system/

But I keep getting the error:

include(User.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I won't post the whole stack trace, but YiiBase.php has an error at line 423:

```
include($className.'.php');
```

Can anyone please help me?

---

But no where in that tutorial does it mention creating a class called user, just LevelLookUp, which is why I am confused :/

---

I think I know where I'm going wrong, I don't have a model!

Could someone explain what I need to do regarding:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $username = strtolower($this->username);
    // from database... change to suite your authentication criteria
    // -- Nope, I wont include mine --
    $user = User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?', array($username));
```

Comment: how are you setting $className? it's a relative path too.

Comment: Um... there's no such file or directory ;-)  $className contains 'User'.  So it's looking for 'User.php' and that's not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first have to create a user table and generate the model of the table. You can generate the model easily using Gii (Yii code generator). According to the tutorial u mentioned, you will have ta add column/field named "level" in your user table.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you've referenced assumes that you already have a 'users' table, and presumably already generated the PHP Model code for it. I suggest you read the [Yii Blog Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/) as it covers a common base.